# Submit two forms at once with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce

Basically my idea is very simple - I want to create a new cart for each new user. The form itself is generated with scaffold and we're talking `rails 4.0.1` here.

Is there a way to do that and if so - how? Maybe you can link me some live examples?

Comment: Just use ajax request to send both forms, like it has described here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Your question needs better definition. It can be interpreted different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need multiple forms to create multiple objects in Rails controller.  Assuming that you have relationships like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carts #or has_one :cart
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then it's perfectly acceptable to do this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new user_params
    if @user.save
      @user.carts.create # or @user.create_cart
      redirect_to user_path
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(...)
    end
end
```

If the new user form happens to include some cart-specific details, then use `fields_for` to make them available in the form:

```
= form_for :user do |f|
  ... f.blah for user fields ...
  = fields_for :cart do |cart_fld|
    ... cart_fld.blah for cart fields ...
```

and add `cart_params` to your controller.